# How to close Google vignette (Google ads) that is randomly popping using Selenide

Tags: ads, ui-automation, selenide

I had several Selenide automated test web sites which have Google Vignette. The google vignette have different iframe id. I cannot close it using automation code due to different google vignette button and different iframe id.

[image]

What is the solution here? Somebody suggest walking through the blur() styling but how? Any other solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait with retries for google ads via JS script and remove it from DOM if it appeared.

Locator for Google Ads looks like `[id*=google_ads_iframe],[id*=ad_iframe]`

So, you call `querySelector` on this element. If it exists - remove it, else retry after 1 second.

```js
function waitForElementAndRemove() {
  let element = document.querySelector('[id*=google_ads_iframe],[id*=ad_iframe]');

  if (element) {
    element.remove();
    console.log('Removed ad');
  } else {
    setTimeout(waitForElementAndRemove, 1000);
  }
}

waitForElementAndRemove();
```

```java
 public void removeElementAsync(String cssLocator) {
        String observerScript = String.format("function waitForElementAndRemove() {" +
                "  let element = document.querySelector('%s');" +
                "  if (element) {" +
                "    element.remove();" +
                "    console.log('Removed ad');" +
                "  } else {" +
                "    setTimeout(waitForElementAndRemove, 1000);" + 
                "  }" +
                "}" +
                "waitForElementAndRemove();", cssLocator);
        Selenide.executeJavaScript(observerScript);
    }
```

Test resource with google vignette

```java
Selenide.open("https://demo.guru99.com/articles_popup.php#google_vignette");
String adsSelector = "[id*=google_ads_iframe],[id*=ad_iframe]";
removeElementAsync(adsSelector);
ElementsCollection elements = $$(".dropdown a").filter(Condition.visible);
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    elements.get(i).click();
    removeElementAsync(adsSelector);
    Selenide.sleep(1000);
}
```