# How to close Google Popup Ad iframe Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, iframe, popup

I am presently employing Selenium for an academic project related to quality assurance automation in Java. I am utilizing a website that I do not have control over or any personal connection to.

I've observed that during the execution of my test cases, advertisements occasionally show up within the Chrome window that launches.

Since it is not a pop-up, I am able to locate the iframe and #document inside it, so I can find the "Close" button

```
//div[@id='dismiss-button']/div/span
```

to close one type of the ad. But there is another type of the ad. I was trying to locate the X button with this:`By.className("btn")`, but not luck. Please help.

```
        addcust.clickAddNewCustomer();
    WebElement frame1 = driver.findElement(By.id("google_ads_iframe_/24132379/INTERSTITIAL_DemoGuru99_0"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(frame1);
        WebElement frame2 = driver.findElement(By.id("ad_iframe"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(frame2);
        try {
            WebElement dismissButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='dismiss-button']/div/span"));
            dismissButton.click();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            // If the first button is not present, click the second button
            WebElement secondButton = driver.findElement(By.className("btn"));
            secondButton.click();
        }
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    }
    }
```

[X button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OncXX.png)
[Close button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrlY4.png)

Comment: try just //div[@id='dismiss-button']  You may also want to use webdriverwait with expected condition of frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt:  https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(org.openqa.selenium.By)  You should probably also return the driver to the main DOM before switching the second time.  switchTo(). defaultContent(); or to parent...

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77657693/how-to-close-google-vignette-google-ads-that-is-randomly-popping-using-selenid/77660116#77660116